# Scheduled Actions on Process Builder are not invoked

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have created a process builder for sending email alerts 30 days before a date field on a record.

So I have added a criteria for activating only when the `status__c` field equals `scheduled`.

Then I have added `Scheduled Actions` to it - to send an email 30 days before the `due_date__c` field value.

For enabling `Scheduled Actions` I had to mark in the criteria, this section as true:

> Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record

But because of that, this criteria does not always happen

My main use case is - if the `status__c` field does not change, and the `due_date__c` field only changes - then the schedule does not happen.

I have tried to add `ISCHANGED` to the `due_date__c` field to the criteria but that is not allowed.

Is there any way to trigger the `Scheduled Actions` always when the `due_date__c` field changes?

Here is a snap of my process:

[image]

**UPDATE**

The error when adding IS CHANGED to the due_date__c field:

[image]

Comment: I didn't quite understand, why you are not able to add `ISCHANGED` criteria. Under operator Instead of equals you will choose `ISCHANGED` and set it to boolean `True`. Is this `ischanged` operator not appearing?

Comment: when I add IS CHANGED to the due_date__c field I get this error ( see also new image on the question): `The Is Changed operator can't be used if you choose the advanced option to execute actions only when specified changes are made to the record. Please change your criteria and try again.`

Answer (score 1):

So when you select yes when prompted "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?"(thus allowing you to create a scheduled action) you are only going to fire the event when you make a change and it explicitly makes all rule criteria true.

The reason you cannot use `ISCHANGED` is how scheduled actions work. At the time scheduled, if the rule criteria still evaluates to true, then the action will fire, which means that in order to use `ISCHANGED`, you would have to store the prior value of the field until at least the scheduled action executes - expensive and not supported.

I would recommend making your second rule criteria 
`due_date__c Not Equal to GlobalConstants.Null`

This will allow your scheduled action to be scheduled upon change of due date.
It will also allow the action to be scheduled in the case where the `status__c` is populated but the `due_date__c` is not.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @MitchSpano, it works nice if the `due_date__c` field was null and then I have added a date, but if the field had a date and I changed it - your solution does not work. Any idea on solving that use case?